# How to stop receiving email notifications for specific comment threads on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, notifications, mute

Whenever I reply to a comment on YouTube, I am automatically subscribed to all replies to that same comment. Usually this is what I want, as the comments emailed to me are usually replies to what I said or at least relevant.

However, other times it gets quite spammy and I stop wanting to receive messages about that thread. At the bottom of all of these emails is "Mute email updates to this post" with "Mute" linked. Clicking this mute button brings me to a Google+ page which has the thread and "Muted" in red. This is all lies, as I continue to receive updates on the comments.

The only way I have found to do this so far is to mark the thread as spam, but then other messages from YouTube that I do want also get marked as spam. Also, not all email clients support this.

How do I stop receiving email notifications for specific comment threads?

Comment: You can set up rules based on the subject line and just sort them into the trash. Not sure if that's within the scope of an answer for you . . .

Answer (score 2):

**Thread-local mute** on the mail client is the best option I've found so far. On Gmail, this means waiting for at least two comments in the same thread so that the option to mute appears. If there's only one comment/email, Gmail gives no option to mute it.

This obviously isn't ideal, there doesn't seem to be any way to mute them on the YouTube side.